# dynamic icon change for markers google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have studied the map class from Google and got to point where I'm able to set markers on locations I want. I wanted to have icons dynamically updated on "mouse events"

```
    var neighborhoods = [
    [54.50266744485844,  18.540940856933616],
    [54.49848076437959,  18.540254211425804],
    [54.49190082846816, 18.518968200683616],
    [54.4040671009359,  18.608918762207054],
    ];

    var markers = [];
    var map;
```

And for to put markers I use function as below.

```
     function setMarkers(map) {

      var image = {
      url: '/images/icon1.png',
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
   };
    var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };


    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
       {
        var neighborhood = neighborhoods[i];
        var marker_temp = new google.maps.Marker
        ({
        position: {lat: neighborhood[0], lng: neighborhood[1]},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: "",
        visible:true,
        zIndex: 3
        });
        marker_temp.addListener('mouseover', function() 
        { 
        marker_temp.setOptions({icon: "/images/icon1.png"});
        });

        marker_temp.addListener('mouseout',  function() 
        { 
        marker_temp.setOptions({icon: "/images/icon2.png"});    
        });

        marker_temp.addListener('click',  function() 
        { 
        marker_temp.setOptions({icon: "/images/icon1.png"});
        });


    markers.push(marker_temp);
}// end of for loop ----------------------------------------------------

     }// --- end of set markers function --------------------------------
```

Putting markers works fine and events on all of them are triggered as expected but only change of the icon from icon1.png to icon2.png works on last marker with events related to all fo them. Can anyone tell me where is error in my thinking ?

Comment: addListener must be set to map not to marker

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have block scope, but function scope. Example:

```
function setMarkers(map) {
....
   for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
   {
    ....
    var marker_temp = new google.maps.Marker
    ....
   }
}
```

The variable `marker_temp` is scoped to the function `setMarkers`, not to the `for`-loop as is usual in other programming languages.

The above is functionally the same as this (the process is called `hoisting`):

```
function setMarkers(map) {
    var marker_temp;
    ....
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
    {
     ....
     marker_temp = new google.maps.Marker
     ....
   }
}
```

That means that when you do this:

```
marker_temp.addListener('click',  function() 
{ 
    marker_temp.setOptions({icon: "/images/icon1.png"});
});
```

When you call `setOptions`, the `marker_temp` variable will be the value that was last set in the loop.

To circumvent the problem you can use an IIFE (inmediately invoked function expression) so you can capture the value of marker variable at that point in time:

```
 marker_temp.addListener('click',  (function(theMarker) 
 { 
    return function(){
        theMarker.setOptions({icon: "/images/icon1.png"});
    }
 })(marker_temp));
```

For more information about scope and hoisting you can read a blog post I wrote about this: https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/20/javascript-hoisting-explained/

Comment: Hi thank You for Your response. it looks I need to learn a bit. I will read about hoisting and come back to what I try to achieve. :) Thank You

Comment: Apologies, I had a few errors in the script. Please review the updated answer

Comment: Hi Thank You.Seems start working but now the markers after clicking move from one location to another (width of cursor) all of the after clicking

Comment: Hi again sorry my mistake due to shape feature, when removed works perfect :) Thank You again for help

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please upvote / accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: You can vote by clicking the arrows next to the answers. Or you can accept the answer by clicking the "v" below the arrows

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to set a number of event listeners, I find it simpler to write a `createMarker` function to hold function closure on the marker for the event listeners. Then call that from inside the loop. One example of a `createMarker` function:

```
function createMarker(neighborhood, idx, bounds, map) {
  var image = {
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  };
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  var marker_temp = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: neighborhood[0],
      lng: neighborhood[1]
    },
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
    title: "" + idx,
    visible: true,
    // zIndex: 3
  });
  bounds.extend(marker_temp.getPosition());

  marker_temp.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });

  marker_temp.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });

  marker_temp.addListener('click', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });
  markers.push(marker_temp);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/53wwgzb3/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  setMarkers(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function setMarkers(map) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      var neighborhood = neighborhoods[i];
      createMarker(neighborhood, i, bounds, map);
    } // end of for loop --------------------------------------
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  } // --- end of set markers function ------------------------

function createMarker(neighborhood, idx, bounds, map) {
  var image = {
    url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png',
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  };
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  var marker_temp = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: neighborhood[0],
      lng: neighborhood[1]
    },
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
    title: "" + idx,
    visible: true,
    // zIndex: 3
  });
  bounds.extend(marker_temp.getPosition());

  marker_temp.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });

  marker_temp.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });

  marker_temp.addListener('click', function() {
    marker_temp.setOptions({
      icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/orange.png",
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
    });
  });
  markers.push(marker_temp);
}
var neighborhoods = [
  [54.50266744485844, 18.540940856933616],
  [54.49848076437959, 18.540254211425804],
  [54.49190082846816, 18.518968200683616],
  [54.4040671009359, 18.608918762207054],
];
var markers = [];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```